# Creating column heading that dynamically increases in SSRS report

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have to create a report that looks like below. All the months are dynamically called through Matrix report. And i am not able to place the heading "Yearly Counts" that also dynamically varies with no of months.

Could you please help me in doing this.

[image]

Comment: Could you give some more details? What do you have now? What is it doing that you aren't expecting it to do?

Comment: Are you saying as the matrix grows the Yearly Counts header stays in place? If so is it part of the same tablix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are able to get the Matrix to dynamically add 1 column per month, but you can't get the "Yearly Counts" cell to work correctly, right?

If you use the following option (right-click on the box to the left of the Month row to get to this menu), you should be able to add a header row above the month headers that will expand to cover as many month columns that dynamically appear:

[image: Pop up menu >> Insert Row >> Outside Group - Above selected]

The Matrix should end up looking like this (in design mode):

[image: Matrix with Yearly Counts Header Row added over Months row]