# Create headings for repeating columns

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I'd like to create a table with subheadings based on a grouping dimension. The parent should not be repeating but somehow it does.

Visual studio design:

[image: Visual Studio design example]

Result:
[image: Visual Studio result column grouping]
Where I would like to display the group title once and centered. How can that be achieved without using a tablix within a tablix?

Thnx in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31731374/creating-column-heading-that-dynamically-increases-in-ssrs-report/31731867#31731867

Comment: Yes indeed, however I'm not able to apply the offered solution. The option to add a row outside of the group is not given.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the parent row is outside the group.

Comment: I am not able to add a row outside the group... Which I am able to after creating a new tablix. However this is part of a more complicated tablix, which I am looking to edit to save some time.

Comment: Could you include a screenshot of where you're clicking and the popup menu you are seeing that is not giving you the suggested option?

Comment: Well actually I have systematically tried every position to right click but none gave me the option to add a row outside the group. I've tried it on every row of the tablix(the grey part before the row) and on all columns and every single field) Adding al those screenshots would be a bit too much I suppose... The menu did appear but the option was to add a row, which would be added within the group. I gave up trying and started over as suggested.